# Is there a built-in conversion from Rust's Ordering::* to integers?

Tags: rust

To increment or decrement something based on whether it's below or above some other value, I can do this:

```
if destination > self.position {
    self.position += 1;
} else if destination < self.position {
    self.position -= 1;
}
```

or this:

```
self.position += match self.position.cmp(&destination) {
    Ordering::Less => {
        1
    }
    Ordering::Greater => {
        -1
    }
    Ordering::Equal => {
        0
    }
}
```

The latter is IMO clearer, but much more verbose. Is there a way convert these `Ordering` values to integers (-1, 0, 1), similar to [PHP's spaceship operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), or otherwise reduce the verbosity of this code?

Comment: You can just write this `Ordering::Less => 1,` in your match arms. The brackets are not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can cast them to signed integers (which can be verified in [the source of cmp::Ordering](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/cmp.rs.html#207-217)):

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Ordering::Less as i8);    // -1
    println!("{}", Ordering::Equal as i32);   // 0
    println!("{}", Ordering::Greater as i64); // 1
}
```

In your case this could be used as follows:

```
self.position -= self.position.cmp(&destination) as i8; // or a different, more suitable signed integer
```

Comment: That should be `self.position -= self.position.cmp(&destination) as i8;`

Answer (score 1):

Like @ljedrz said, you can convert the `Ordering` to an integer. Another option, which may be clearer is to remember that you can use `if` as an expression:

```
self.position += if destination > self.position      {  1 }
                 else if destination < self.position { -1 }
                 else                                {  0 };
```